# .NET Data Adapter for Oracle Cloud

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Good day all,

I am going to test my .NET application with Oracle Cloud, it works excellent with Oracle 11g R2, but I don't know whether .NET Data Adapter exists for Oracle Cloud or not.

Does anyone know the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No way: we have to use Java or Web Services but not .NET (for now):

http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/CSDBU/develop.htm#CSDBU195

http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/CSJSU/intro.htm#CSJSU7053